# How to force CRM Outlook UserSettings for Activity Forms

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to force Outlook CRM users to use the CRM Forms for appointment, contact, Email and Task.  This is controlled via the UserSettings.UseCrmFormForAppointment, UserSettings.UseCrmFormForContact, UserSettings.UseCrmFormForEmail, UserSettings.UseCrmFormForTask, attributes.  I was planning creating a plugin for the UserSettings entity, but when I use the registration tool, it say's "Invalid Primary Entity".

Is there a way to use register the plugin a different way?  How do I force outlook CRM users to use the CRM Forms for activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SDK (specifically the spreadsheet at "\sdk\tools\message-entity support for plug-ins.xlsx") the `UserSettings` entity only supports the `RetrieveMultiple` message.

Perhaps you could register your plugin on `create` of a `systemuser` record instead? Granted this won't prevent the user from changing it but it would at least set the default. There is also the (outside) chance that changes to User Settings cause an `update` to the `systemuser` record (I'm only speculating though). In which case, you might be able to trap that event too and enforce a no-change policy.

Comment: I've tested and confirmed that updates to the UseCRMForm fields do not cause the SystemUser to update.  Currently we're thinking a plugin on the create of the system user, and some utility that runs every hour to find any users that have updated their settings, and change them back.

Comment: I wonder if they are issued via an `Execute` message instead? Not the best message to hook into for plug-ins, but it might avoid the need for an external component. If you do write a plug-in for `Execute` make sure you check the data coming in as early and as 'lightly' as you can as `Execute` is used a lot internally so you can easy introduce unwanted overhead on unrelated use cases.